# Use the same template for several functions

Tags: c++, templates

If several functions which use the same template are needed, is there a way to declare and implement them without declaring the template each time?

```
template <typename T>
T mymax (T a, T b);
template <typename T>
T mymin (T a, T b);
template <typename T>
T myfoo (T a, T b);

/********************************************/
template <typename T>
T mymax (T a, T b) {
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}

template <typename T>
T mymin (T a, T b) {
    return (a < b ? a : b);
}
template <typename T>
T myfoo (T a, T b) {
    return max(a,b)+min(a,b);
}
```

Is there a way to write the line `template <typename T>` just one time for a block of code? Something that will look like:

```
template <typename T> {
  T mymax (T a, T b);
  T mymin (T a, T b);
  T myfoo (T a, T b);
}
```

(this code isn't legal syntax and doesn't compile)

Comment: No.  Wait for concepts.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is making them all static functions in a class template. But then you need `ClassName::mymax()` everywhere, so you haven't really gained much.

Comment: `myfoo` is a really convoluted way to write `mysum`...

Comment: @T.C. All of these functions are just dummy functions that I wrote for testing and to give as an example in the question. `myfoo` is an example for a `template` function that has other `template` functions embedded inside.

Comment: Since no-one else is saying it I'll say it: Macro.

Comment: @DanielFrey, please explain and demonstrate.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed I found a better solution/option, see my answer. But if you really want to know about macros: `#define MYFUNC(NAME) template<typename T> T NAME(T a, T b)` and use `MYFUNC(mymin); MYFUNC(mymax); MYFUNC(myfoo);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve something like this is to misuse a struct and static functions. Unfortunately, you'll need to explicitly mention the template type.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct my
{
  static T max(T a, T b) { return (a > b ? a : b); }
  static T min(T a, T b) { return (a < b ? a : b); }
  static T foo(T a, T b) { return max(a, b) + min(a, b); }
};
```

[Live Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea6e972e2574b999) Pick a better class name.

I can't think any "better" solution. Just write the `template<typename T>`. You'll get used to it. It serves a purpose, and it really isn't as ugly as you think.

Comment: [My question about this was marked a duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320369/alias-of-a-function-template). But your answer does not really solve my problem. I need the declarations and definitions to be separate. Your solution still requires  writing out the declaration for each except without the template. That's still redundant. I don't mean to criticize but can't the preprocessor be used to do this better?

Comment: @Zboson I reopened your question as it is indeed not a duplicate. But please rephrase/expand on your issue. As it stands, it is very unclear what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to make the code shorter, but it is actually the exact opposite of what you are asking for: You can *not* leave out the `template<...>`-part, but you can simplify the rest:

```
// create a shortcut for the function type
template<typename T>
using my = T( T a, T b );

// declare several functions with an identical signature
template<typename T> my<T> mymin;
template<typename T> my<T> mymax;
template<typename T> my<T> myfoo;
```

Note that this works for the declarations only, the definitions will not benefit from this.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d52ad0f2b334a9b9)